# What is the proper format for comparing a variable to a string in C?

Tags: c, string, variables, comparison

I'm trying to write a function in C that will query the user for input and then do a specific set of tasks based upon that input.  The code I came up with looks like this:

```
int exit = 1;

int main(void)
{
    while (exit)
    {
        action();
    }
}

void action()
{
    char x[31];
    fgets(x, 30, stdin);
    chomp(x);

    if (x == "stop")
    {
        exit = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I type "stop" into the console, it doesn't register, and the loop just keeps going forcing me to CTRL-C.  So what is wrong with the comparison?  I had it print x after I entered it and it prints out "stop", so I don't understand why the if statement isn't working...

By the way the chomp() function is of my own design, it just removes the first /n and replaces it with a /0.

Comment: Minor:  Use the _size_ in `fgets()` like `fgets(x, 31, stdin);` or even better `fgets(x, sizeof x, stdin);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either strcmp() or strncmp() function to compare two strings in your code. Please look into following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int exit_code = 1;

void action()
{
    char x[31];
    fgets(x, 30, stdin);

    if ( (strncmp(x,"stop",4)) == 0)
    {
        printf("Both Strings are equal....\n");
        exit_code = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    while (exit_code)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a string compare function, either `strcmp()` or, if you only care about the first n characters then `strncmp()`. Refer to the [C library reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcmp) on how to use it.